# How to set up a SQL Server Cartridge with Red Hat OpenShift?

Tags: sql-server, tomcat7, openshift

I have recently signed up for an OpenShift Online account and successfully deployed a basic Tomcat 7 web application. I am now interested in interacting with a SQL Server database, which I am led to believe is a supported database engine (at least by the wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenShift and a few blog posts). However, I have been unable to figure out how to add a SQL Server cartridge, if one even exists.

Would someone be able to supply some basic instructions?

Comment: can you show what you have tried already?  this site works best when you show some effort

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to using MSSQL server, then that is not an available cartridge for OpenShift Online.  You would need to use something that runs on Linux (MySQL, MongoDB, Redis, etc).  You can, however, try signing up for a DBaaS that provides MSSQL and connect to it from your OpenShift gear.  If you are just trying to add a MySQL cartridge, log into the web console at openshift.com, then click on your application, and click on the "see the list of cartridges you can add" link near the bottom of the page.  There you will be presented with a list of cartridges that you can add to your existing application, such as mysql, mongodb, phpmyadmin, etc.